# integral $\int_{}^{}\frac{dx}{1+x^4+x^8} $

Tags: integration, rational-functions

looking for help for the following integral -

$$
\int_{}^{}\frac{dx}{1+x^4+x^8} 
$$

what I tried to do:

$$\int_{}^{}\frac{dx}{1+x^4+x^8}  = \int_{}^{}\frac{dx}{\frac14+x^4+x^8 + \frac{3}{4}}= \int_{}^{}\frac{dx}{\left(x^4+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4}} $$

and now I am stuck :-(

Comment: $$1+x^4+x^8=(1+x^4)^2-(x^2)^2=(1-x^2+x^4)(1+x^2+x^4)$$

Comment: FYI: Polynomials are sums of powers of variables (multiplied by constants) such that the exponents are non-negative integers. Ratios of those are called rational functions. So $1+x^4+x^8$ is a polynomial. $1/(1+x^4+x^8)$ is a rational function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factorise the denominator $x^8+x^4+1=(x^4+x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{3}x+1)(x^2-\sqrt{3}x+1)$. Now do partial fractions
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{1+x^4+x^8}=\frac{1}{4(1+x+x^2)}+\frac{1}{4(1-x+x^2)}+\frac{2x+\sqrt{3}}{4\sqrt{3}(1+\sqrt{3}x+x^2)}-\frac{2x-\sqrt{3}}{4\sqrt{3}(1-\sqrt{3}x+x^2)}
\end{eqnarray*}
Each of these terms can be integrated using standard logs and inverse tangents.

Answer (score 0):

I want to present another method such that we calculate 2 partial fractions incited of 4 partial fractions. By substitution  $\frac{1}{x}=t$ we have  $dx=-\frac{1}{t^2}dt$ and we obtain the form $J$ that is equal the form $I$ as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
I=\int\,\frac{dx}{1+x^4+x^8} \\
\\
J=\int\, \frac{-\frac{1}{t^2}dt}{1+{(\frac{1}{t})}^4+{(\frac{1}{t})}^8}
=J=\int\, \frac{-\frac{1}{t^2}dt}{\frac{t^8+t^4+1}{t^8}}=
\int\,\frac{-t^6\,dt}{1+t^4+t^8}
\end{array}
$$
which results that
$$
2\,I=I+J=\int\,\frac{(1-t^6)\,dt}{1+t^4+t^8}=
\int \, \frac{(1-t^2)(1+t^4+t^8)\,dt}{(t^4+t^2+1)(t^4-t^2+1)}
=\int\, \frac{(1-t^2)\, dt}{(t^4-t^2+1)}
$$

Comment: Hi I didn't understand the J move how does it work how the t^-2 turned into t^6?

Comment: The form $J$ is obtained by  integration by parts formula that is equal to form $I$. I edit my post to clarify how $t^6$ is calculated.